# How can I make a div expand to the height of the page?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the blue div expand to the height of the page but nothing seems to work:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyt83gow/)

css:

```
/* Reset */
html,body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
}

/* General */
.clear {
    clear:both;
}

/* Page Layout */
#page {
    margin-left:250px;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:green;
}

#main {
    float:right;
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    height:100%;
}

#sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    margin-left:-250px;
    background-color:#222629;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

and html:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="main">
        main
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           ...
           <li>something</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The same needs to hold true for the sidebar if the page is much longer than the sidebar content.

Comment: I am having a hard time relating your question title to its content - can you explain the association?

Comment: the title was a mistake from a previous question.  just fixed it.  - thanks

Comment: That doesn't work.  It collapses the green div and leaves white-space below the blue.

Comment: I get good results by [adding `position: relative` to `#page` and `position: absolute` to `#main`](https://jsfiddle.net/qyt83gow/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the bottom of the fiddle, I think its what you want.

```
#main {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ac1p22r4/

here it is with some extra touchup
https://jsfiddle.net/ssj3xtr7/

Comment: viewport unit vh (viewport Height) and vw (viewport Width) 
https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-viewport-units/

Answer (score 0):

Because div doesn't contain anything so it will not expanding.

You can give `position:fixed` to make blue div to expand to height of page.

```
#main {
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Check: https://jsfiddle.net/qyt83gow/1/

Another option is give `min-height` to that div.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the **height** attribute's value of **#main** and **#sidebar** like this:

```
#main, #sidebar {
   height: 100vh;
}
```

This stretches the height of the div to the page's height.
Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Reset */
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

/* General */
.clear {
    clear: both;
}

/* Page Layout */
#page {

    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#main {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;

    display: table-cell;
}

#sidebar {
     background-color: #00FF00;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #222629;

}
```

updated link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qyt83gow/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function resize () {
    var x = $('#page').height();
    $('#main').css('height',x+'px');
}

$(document).ready (function(){
    resize();
})

$(window).resize(function(){ 
    resize();
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyt83gow/9/)

Comment: The question isn't tagged with JavaScript, let alone jQuery.

Comment: Maybe because when he put the code in, JS nor JQuery weren't options to pick because he hadn't put a single line of JS code in his question? He didn't specifically ask for it to be pure CSS, or rather, he didn't say JQuery was a no-no.

Comment: Much like using the handle of a screwdriver to smash a nail into wood eventually *works* :)

Comment: You're selling JQuery short:

http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71w4WpgZHGL._SL1500_.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is correct, but one mistake in your css is, there are lot more content in sidebar which is increasing height of that sidebar. Just put `overflow:auto` or `overflow-y:auto;` to add a scrollbar to sidebar, which will give you expected result.

Here is complete CSS

```
/* Reset */
html,body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
}

/* General */
.clear {
    clear:both;
}

/* Page Layout */
#page {
    margin-left:250px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:green;
}

#main {
    float:right;
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    height:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
}

#sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    margin-left:-250px;
    background-color:#222629;
    max-height:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Here is Fiddle.[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/qyt83gow/6/)

My suggestion is, **don't use vm** as it doesn't support some browsers and partially support to some. [Here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) is support map

Answer (score 0):

```
use class expand-panel on both div sidebar and menu.
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.clear {
   clear: both;
}
#page {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.expand-panel {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}
#main {
    background-color: blue;
}
#sidebar {
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give height in px or give this class (margin:5 or 10px;)